# Ember - Setting homepage title in controller or route?

Tags: ember.js

What is the best practice?

This is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div id="top-panel">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Where should I set {{title}}? I found out there are two ways to do this...

First:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set("title", "Foo Bar")
    }
});
```

Second:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    title: "Hello World"
});
```

Which one is a recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a static thing that will never change, I'd put it in the second, or just in the handlebars template.

Additionally

1. since you aren't setting an object on the application controller, it doesn't really need to extend the ObjectController, you can just extend Controller.

   ```
   Ember.ObjectController is part of Ember's Controller layer. It is intended to 
   wrap a single object, proxying unhandled attempts to get and set to the 
   underlying content object, and to forward unhandled action attempts to its target.
   ```
2. In the future, if you are overriding the setupController it's usually recommended to call this._super(controller, model) like:

   ```
   setupController: function (controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model)
      controller.set("title", "Foo Bar")
   }
   ```

setupController's default implementation is to set the content on the controller, so technically it makes no difference that you aren't calling super.

In the case of a dynamic title, I'd make it a computed property:

```
 App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     title: function(){
        var currentdate = new Date(),
            title = "Awesome Title: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();

          return title;
     }.property()
 });
```

Comment: It will be dynamic - it will be something like "Reports for 18th October 2013" - so the title will be based on date. Would your answer change in that case?

Comment: I'd use a computed property, see above.