# Page Titles in Application template per-route - what's the right way to do this?

Tags: ember.js

In my app, I'm changing the page title per route. However, the page title is outside the main {{outlet}} I'm using, i.e:

application.handlebars:

```
<h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>

{{outlet}}
```

I want to set pageTitle in the child controllers for each route, so this is what I'm doing:

```
App.WidgetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @._super(controller, model)
    @controllerFor('application').set('pageTitle', 'Widgets')
```

Is this the right way to do this? I noticed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446361/ember-setting-homepage-title-in-controller-or-route), but the answer there didn't explain how to do this for titles that only change per-child controller and aren't necessarily calculable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `setTitle` action in your `ApplicationRoute`, which could set the `pageTitle` in the `ApplicationController`:

```
// routes/application.js
actions: {
  setTitle: function(title) {
    this.get('controller').set('title', title);
  }
}
```

and then maybe in the `init` function for a child route or controller. just send the action with the title you want, it should bubble up to the application route:

```
  init: function() {
    this.send('setTitle', 'My Page Title');
    this._super();
  },
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that automatically? Or do I need to call that every time in the child controllers?

Comment: Just call it when you need to update the title, or you can create a base controller, that has this behavior by default that reads a `title` property.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly simpler way of doing this (which also seems to be implied by the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController)) is this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    this.controllerFor('application').set('pageTitle', 'Main title for page');
}
```

**Edit**

An even better way is using an *initializer* that reopens the `Route` class (assuming you use ember-cli, which you should)

```
// app/initializers/setup-route.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize() {
  Ember.Route.reopen({
    mainTitle: '',
    breadcrumbs: [],
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);

      var app = this.controllerFor('application');

      if(app) {
        app.set('mainTitle', this.mainTitle);
        app.set('breadcrumbs', this.breadcrumbs);
      }
    }
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'setup-route',
  initialize: initialize
};




// and in the route file

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  mainTitle: 'Dashboard WIP',
});
```