# Ember - Set a Dynamic Page Title per route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-pods

I have set up my Ember app to use the pod structure. I've created a topbar-nav component which I display on the main page. In the topbar-nav component I have set up the page title, which I would like to set automatically per route so for the **dashboard** route the title should be Dashboard, for the **dashboard/categories** the title should be categories and so on.

Here's my app structure:

- app

  - application
  - components

    - topbar-nav
  - dashboard
  - categories

The app router - router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('dashboard', function() {
    this.route('categories');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

And the templates:

application/template.hbs

```
<aside>
    {{sidebar-nav}}
</aside>

<main>
    <header>
        {{topbar-nav}}
    </header>

    {{outlet}}
</main>
```

components/topbar-nav/template.hbs

```
<nav class="topbar-nav">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h5 class="page-title">{{title}}</h5>
    </div>
</nav>

{{yield}}
```

components/topbar-nav/component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    title: 'Component title'
});
```

As you can tell already the title I get rendered is '**Component title**'

The most accurate answer I got by now is this one:

[Ember dynamic titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588250/page-titles-in-application-template-per-route-whats-the-right-way-to-do-this)

though after trying a lot of different approaches I couldn't find a good solution.

Is there a clean and easy way of doing this? Any ideas and solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: There is a good addon for dynamic document title. You can take a look at its source code, maybe it will help you to make a good solution https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-document-title

Comment: The titles that you want to display, are they always the name of the route with first letter capitalised?

Comment: @AcidBurn Usually the the last node of the path. So for example if the path is dashboard/categories, the title will be Categories. Thanks!

Comment: @GennadyDogaev thanks for the resource. I also had a look into that which gave me some insight on a different approach but still couldn't make this work.

Comment: Your `application controller` will have a property named `currentRouteName`. You can observe this property and extract the title needed using some javascript functions.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a similar dynamic title and found this page. So here is my solution based on @AcidBurn's note that the `application controller` has a `currentRouteName` property.

### If you want the last child route:

```
screen_title: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function () {
    let route = this.get('currentRouteName').split('.');

    // Return last route name (e.g. categories from dashboard.categories)
    return route[route.length - 1];
}),
```

### If you want the parent route:

```
screen_title: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function () {
    let route = this.get('currentRouteName').split('.');

    // Return parent route name (e.g. reports from reports.index)
    return route[0];
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

ember-page-title seems better than ember-cli-document-title now (better docs+api)